# Python 'Unknown flags on get' error while querying memcached

Tags: python, memcached

I have pretty straightforward Python code which queries data from memcached:

```
import memcache 
client = memcache.Client([('127.0.0.1', 11211)])
res = client.get("data_e")
```

*data_e* key exists, is not null and I am able to get results via telnet connection to memcached.
However when Python script is executed I keep receiving following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./position_expiration.py", line 5, in <module>
    res = client.get("data_e")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 1129, in get
    return self._get('get', key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 1113, in _get
    return _unsafe_get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 1101, in _unsafe_get
    value = self._recv_value(server, flags, rlen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 1294, in _recv_value
    raise ValueError('Unknown flags on get: %x' % flags)
ValueError: Unknown flags on get: 20
```

Data in memcached is stored by third party service, so I can't change a way how it is written there. What can I do from client side with Python to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

This is the solution in Chinese: https://www.cnblogs.com/LanTianYou/p/9204431.html

The solution is to modify the final else-block content in the method "_recv_value" in the python file "memcache.py".

The _recv_value method should be like this:

```
def _recv_value(self, server, flags, rlen):
    rlen += 2  # include \r\n
    buf = server.recv(rlen)
    if len(buf) != rlen:
        raise _Error("received %d bytes when expecting %d"
                     % (len(buf), rlen))

    if len(buf) == rlen:
        buf = buf[:-2]  # strip \r\n

    if flags & Client._FLAG_COMPRESSED:
        buf = self.decompressor(buf)
        flags &= ~Client._FLAG_COMPRESSED
    if flags == 0:
        # Bare bytes
        val = buf
    elif flags & Client._FLAG_TEXT:
        val = buf.decode('utf-8')
    elif flags & Client._FLAG_INTEGER:
        val = int(buf)
    elif flags & Client._FLAG_LONG:
        if six.PY3:
            val = int(buf)
        else:
            val = long(buf)  # noqa: F821
    elif flags & Client._FLAG_PICKLE:
        try:
            file = BytesIO(buf)
            unpickler = self.unpickler(file)
            if self.persistent_load:
                unpickler.persistent_load = self.persistent_load
            val = unpickler.load()
        except Exception as e:
            self.debuglog('Pickle error: %s\n' % e)
            return None
    else:
        self.debuglog("unknown flags on get: %x\n" % flags)
        # 注释掉这行
        # raise ValueError('Unknown flags on get: %x' % flags)
        # 设定返回值
        val = buf

    return val
```

Comment: didnt explained what was the issue, you only copied the solution.